# Can you use C++14s single quote (') digit separator with non-integer types?

Tags: c++, c++14

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal C++14 allows the single quote separator in integer types to help with readability:

> Optional single quotes(') may be inserted between the digits as a separator. They are ignored by the compiler. [since C++14]

However, my question is whether it is safe to use it for floating point numbers too? The following code compiles without warnings for me, however, I'm concerned whether any implicit casting is happening due to the separator in the float:

```
int main()
{
    int foo = 1'000;
    float bar = 1'000.f;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Comment: they're valid in floating point literals too https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Comment: the page on floating literals has the same statement as the one you are quoting for integer literals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they are allowed. Looking at the [floating-point literal page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) we have the same quote

> Optional single quotes (') may be inserted between the digits as a separator; they are ignored during compilation.   (since C++14)

Comment: Ah, I looked for that page and ended up looking in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types instead. That's silly of me. That clears it, thanks.